# Search query parser recognises tags regardless of case, but search itself does not

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

For example, when searching for `JavaScript alert`, `JavaScript` is recognised by the parser as a tag (and wrapped in square brackets), but this is then not recognised in the search itself and so no matches are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excellent catch. Fixed!